# Cannot set Spark memory

Tags: java, memory, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to set max memory for a Spark application running locally. 
I have tried many different ways.

In the program

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
conf.setMaster("local[2]");
conf.setAppName("app");     
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "4G");
conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "4G");
sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

And when executing

```
./bin/spark-submit.cmd ./local/app.jar --master local[2] --driver-memory 4G
```

But I always get the following

```
INFO [MemoryStore] MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
```

and Spark spills RDD to disk.
Spark version is 2.0.

What could I do?

Comment: did you try small 'g' ?

Comment: @numX I tried small g and the results are same.

Answer (score 6):

In local mode your executor is your driver and it is therefore a fraction of your heap. 
By the time `spark-submit` is executed the JVM has already been launched, so you need to pass in the `--driver-memory` arg. For example:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory 4g --class MyClass spark-app-1.0.jar
```

will start the JVM with 4G.

Order also seems to matter i.e. `--driver-memory` needs to come before `--class`

Comment: This helped me out! The order of the arguments is indeed important!

Comment: This helped me! For PySpark, `spark-submit --driver-memory 30g xxx.py` works well, but `spark-submit  xxx.py --driver-memory 30g` failed

Answer (score 2):

When running locally, spark will not used more memory then the java process has available.
You should try running your application with extra memory vm params: -Xms2048m -Xmx4096m

Comment: This also does not work. But I change Spark version to 1.6.1 and it is OK now.

Answer (score 0):

The `spark.driver.memory` works for local running instance in Spark 2.

Spark forbids '-Xms' and converts `spark.driver.memory` into '-Xmx'.